# can i send a server control from the aspx.cs page

Tags: asp.net

can i send a server control from the aspx.cs page

Comment: Send it where?  And what do you mean by send?

Comment: i want to send a linkbutton control from the aspx.cs page to the .aspx page but it is not properly working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "send" you mean "create", then you can do it easily by adding the dynamically created control to a container such as the Page or a Panel:

```
LinkButton lnk1 = new LinkButton();
// Set any required properties.
...

// Add the control to the container.
Panel1.Controls.Add(lnk1);
```

The LinkButton will be rendered at the client as expected.

Answer (score 0):

add a label to your form

in your code behind file [cs file]

```
label1.Text="<a href='your url'>LinkButton</a>";
```

Comment: I fail to see how this would help in creating a LinkButton control instance in the page?

Comment: Adding a control declaration to the Text property like that isn't going to do anything except render out the declaration as text on the page.

Comment: well have you tried it ?

Comment: have a look at this page
http://www.maconstateit.net/tutorials/ASPNET1/ASPNET03/aspnet03-01.aspx

Comment: ok sorry works only with html controls
it cant render server controls

Comment: @Searock: Zhaph - Ben Duguid is quite correct. Try to understand what is happening here... When you insert HTML markup into the text value of a control, it is rendered on the client as-is. It does not become a part of the Page controls collection. On a side note, I wanted to give you a vote just for mentioning David Adams' tutorials (one of my favourites!), but as you can see, your answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You do it directly also.

Pages.Controls.Add(yourcontrolpathhere)