# Dynamically create a ASP.net Submit LinkButton using a Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to implement an application which will dynamically create a list with a button next to each item on that list.  I am partially able to do this using the Panel control in the aspx page and adding html dynamically in the code behind.  I am having problems adding the LinkButton dynamically which will do database work based on which ID it is.  Is this even possible with what I have?:

aspx:

```
<asp:Panel ID="ItemPanel" runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
```

code behind:

```
...
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string UserID;

while (dr.Read())
{
    UserID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["UserID"]);
    sb.Append("<div><b class='template'></b>");
    //Create LinkButton with event and code behind function
}

ItemPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(sb.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [this very recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876636/can-i-send-a-server-control-from-the-aspx-cs-page/) and if you have additional queries, then edit your question.

**Edit** (after OP's comment)

---

The purpose of posting that link was to give you an idea how to create the control dynamically. Since you ask, here's a simple bare-bones ASPX page that creates a LinkButton and attaches an eventhandler for the `Click` event. Not sure what you mean by "handle changes on the server", though.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    LinkButton lnk1 = new LinkButton();
    lnk1.Text = "Click me!";

    //lnk1.PostBackUrl = "SomeOtherPage.aspx";

    // Use the eventhandler to perform redirection, 
    // instead of the PostBackUrl to show it works.
    lnk1.Click += new EventHandler(lnk1_Click);

    // Add control to container:
    pnl1.Controls.Add(lnk1);
  }

  void lnk1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Response.Redirect("SomeOtherPage.aspx");
  }

</script>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a different question or more advanced. I am asking for help on creating a linkbutton but also the ability to create the code behind onclick event as well to handle changes on the server. Thanks